# Array and var - how to change and two

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I have `js` `array` and `var` like this:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var variable = array[0];
```

But how if I change variable i auto change and element of array: `array[0]`?

```
variable = 44;
// array now is [44, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Only `objects` are mutable...

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **no**.

You're changing the value of  `variable`, it starts with a copy of the value of `array[0]`: the number 1. You then change its value to 44, but there is no link to `array` and there never was. With value types (like numbers) you always copy the value when assigning.

If you want to better understand things like type coercion in JS. I suggest reading free book [YDKJS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS).

Comment: YDKJS is You Dont Know JS, but I know JS ...
And I know that: "Only objects are mutable... " (this is comment of my question) 
I ask this because i think there are any way to make this (in the questin)  ...

Comment: Speaking simply, you're overwriting value held by variable with new value. `variable` never held reference to array it only held 0 index value.
YDKJS is actually written for people who actively develop in JavaScript but want to better understand its behaviour.